# php and sql. Can't echo the query

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm running into a problem while doing Homework

```
 <form class="" action="" method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" name="datebegin" value="">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Reprot</button>
 <table class="table table-striped" class="problem1">
    <?php
    Display();
    ?>
   </table>
```

This's form function.php

```
<?php
function Display(){
global $conn;
global $datebegin;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$datebegin = $_POST['datebegin'];
print($datebegin);
}
$query="SELECT Guest_name FROM form WHERE datediff($datebegin,datein) = '0'";
<tr>
<th>Guest name</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Guest_name'] . "</td>/tr>";
}
?>
```

From my database

```
  Guest_name   |  datein         
  David        |  2017-12-04
```

when i input the value '2017-12-04'
the print($datebegin) display 2017-12-04
but echo Guest_name won't display David
Thanks you for your time.

Comment: Where do you execute your query? Also datein is not a variable? Maybe you need `$datein`

Comment: also function is in another file? (you are using two different files?)

Comment: The initial opening <?php is not closed either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

function Display(){
global $conn;
global $datebegin;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $datebegin = $_POST['datebegin'];
    print($datebegin);
}
$query="SELECT Guest_name FROM form WHERE datediff($datebegin,$datein) = '0'";
?>
<tr>
<th>Guest name</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" .$row['Guest_name']. "</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

Try this, you did not close your php tag before you used html. I hope this solves the error for you and also fixed some more mistakes in your code. But for sure this is not the full code as i can't see where your query is executed and where your `$datein` variable is coming from inside your `datediff` function.  Also `datediff` is used in `SELECT` and expects 2 string parameters so probably your query is also wrong.